# How to set up Laravel 5.11 environment?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to have 2 different configurations with 2 database connections, one is in my localhost, other is in shared hosting. How to configure .ENV correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/database.php` you need to create a secondary connection:

```
    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      =>  ENV('SHARED_HOSTING_HOST'),
        'database'  =>  ENV('SHARED_HOSTING_DB_NAME'),
        'username'  =>  ENV('SHARED_HOSTING_DB_USER'),
        'password'  =>  ENV('SHARED_HOSTING_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Then in your `.env` you're free to define `SHARED_HOSTING_HOST`, etc.

You can use this secondary connection in a multitude of ways:

In the application code:

```
class SomeController extends BaseController {

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $someModel = new SomeModel;

        $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');

        $something = $someModel->find(1);

        return $something;


  }

}
```

Per model:

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

On the Database Facade:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

On the Schema Facade:

```
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('some_table', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id'):
});
```

[Found at](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)